# Is it possible to confirm multiple PaymentIntents with only one user 3d verification with Stripe?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I have spring boot/angular application integrated with Stripe.

We are trying to include 3d-secured authorization with our existing system. Basic flow with instant automatic and manual confirmation was easy to implement and it is working as a charm , but...

We have a specific case where we have multiple services and some of them are charged (captured)instantly and some of them needs to be confirmed by providers, 
and captured after this confirmation. In our current implementation we are creating separate Charges 
for each asynchronous service(the one that needs confirmation) and in case that confirmation is successful, we capture the Charge. So we have one user action but multiple captures.

Now we are now trying to do the same with PaymentIntent, but it looks like that PaymentIntent can have only one Charge and cannot be partially confirmed. Also, if we create multiple PaymentIntents, even with same paymentMethodId, 
it looks like we need separate user action for each.

Is there any way to support multiple charges or multiple PaymentIntents with only 1 user action, to avoid 3d secure verification for every asynchronous capture?

Update No1:
I manage to implement this using SetupIntent but only for the cards that allows you to do the one-time verification and you can use it later for other payments:

```
 @PostMapping("/createSetup")
    public String createPaymentSetup(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
        SetupIntent setupIntent = SetupIntent.create(params);
        return setupIntent.getClientSecret();
    }
```

This client secret will be used on front to invoke 3d-verification (still without any actual payment):

```
this.stripe.handleCardSetup(
            this.clientSecret, this.cardElement, {
              payment_method_data: {
                billing_details: {name: this.cardholderName.value}
              }
            }
          ).then((result) =>  {
            if (result.error) {
              console.log(result.error);
            } else {
                console.log(result);
                console.log("Setup Intent id: " + result.setupIntent.id);
              this.saveCardForFutureUse(result.setupIntent.id);
            }
          });
        });
```

And in saveCardForFutureUse I'm calling back to attach payment method from this setup with the customer:

```
String setupIntentId = request.getHeader("paymentId");
        SetupIntent intent = SetupIntent.retrieve(setupIntentId);
        PaymentMethod paymentMethod = PaymentMethod.retrieve(intent.getPaymentMethod());
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("customer", "{CUSTOMER_ID}");
        paymentMethod.attach(params);
```

and after that we can create several PaymentIntents with given paymentMethod:

```
PaymentIntentCreateParams bid1Params = PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder()
                .setAmount(3099l)
                .setCurrency("usd")
                .setConfirm(true)
                .setPaymentMethod(paymentMethod.getId())
                .setCustomer("CUSTOMER_ID")
                .setOffSession(true)
                .build();



        PaymentIntentCreateParams bid2Params = PaymentIntentCreateParams.builder()
                .setAmount(5099l)
                .setCurrency("usd")
                .setConfirm(true)
                .setPaymentMethod(paymentMethod.getId())
                .setCustomer("CUSTOMER_ID")
                .setOffSession(true) 
                .build();
        PaymentIntent bid1 = PaymentIntent.create(bid1Params);
        PaymentIntent bid2 = PaymentIntent.create(bid2Params);
```

And if we use correct card like:

> 4000002500003155  Required on setup or first transaction

Those 2 bids paymentIntents will be confirmed... 
If we use card like:

> 4000002760003184  Required    This test card requires authentication on
>   all transactions.

they will still be in status

> "requires_action"

So, it looks like for those cards I need this 3d for every payment...

Answer (score 1):

PaymentIntents actually do support authorization and capture, as the Charge API before it did: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-capture_method

Given what you described, one way to go about it would be to create 1 PaymentIntent, authorized up to the maximum amount you have to charge. Then, once you have gone through the flow with your providers and you have a summed up final value that you want to capture, you would then capture the PaymentIntent up to that value.

Alternatively, you could reuse the card details from the first PaymentIntent (or SetupIntents) for later as explained here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/reusing-cards#saving-cards-after-payment.

Comment: I'm trying to reuse card from the first PaymentIntent but even after confirm, status is still "requires_action", so no luck with that. For the proposal to wait and sum up all, we need to confirm instant payment instantly, so we can only confirm/capture all of them as one, and later refund if provider decline some of the offer, but we would like to avoid this if possible...

Comment: Hi Djordje, it looks like you could use SetupIntents to accomplish this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards#saving-card-without-payment

Create a SetupIntent to collect the user's payment method and optimize any future transactions for off session payments.

Comment: I tried it, created SetupIntent, and confirmed it (with 3d-secure verification), attached payment method to the customer for future use. Later I created 2 PaymentIntents, with this paymentMethodId, but even when I confirm them, they are still in "requires_action" status, not sussess as I expected since my payment method was verified...

Comment: And if I set those 2 new paymentIntents to off-session, I get the error that the card was declined, it requires authentication: Your card was declined. This transaction requires authentication.; code: authentication_required

Comment: With the 3184 card, it is expected that regardless of setup, that test card will require authentication every time. In that case, you would need to bring your user on session to authenticate with 3DS or give them the option to use a new PaymentMethod. 

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/testing#regulatory-cards